# Sorting array of Points by the angles to the base point in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to implement Graham algorithm for finding convex hull in C#. It includes the step of sorting points by their angle to the base point. I'm trying to implement it with Array.Sort  method using class inherited from Comparer.

Here is the class

```
class ReversePolarSorter : Comparer<Point>
    {
        double e = 0.000001;
        double m_baseX;
        double m_baseY;
        public ReversePolarSorter(Point basePoint)
        {
            m_baseX = basePoint.X;
            m_baseY = basePoint.Y;
        }

        public override int Compare(Point a,  Point b)
        {


            double angleA = Math.Atan2(a.Y - m_baseY, a.X - m_baseX);
            double angleB= Math.Atan2(b.Y - m_baseY, b.X - m_baseX);
            int result;
            if (Math.Abs(angleA - angleB) < e)
                result= 0;
            else
                result= angleA.CompareTo(angleB);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And then I'm using it to sort with

```
Comparer<Point> sorter = new ReversePolarSorter(coords[m_pointsNumber-1]);
Array.Sort<Point>(coords, 0, m_pointsNumber - 2, sorter);
```

coords is an array of points.
m_pointsNumber is a number of points.
m_pointsNumber-1 is a base point used to compute angles.

It doesn't sort it in a proper order and I can't see the problem. I would appreciate if somebody could to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compare implementation using epsilon is incorrect.

As we know, if `a == b` and `b == c`, then `a == c`. But this implementation may lead to `a == b`, `b == c`, but `a < c`, which will break the sorting algorithm.

Since you have a base point, you can use rounding rather than epsilon:

```
class ReversePolarSorter : Comparer<Point>
{
    const int precision = 6;
    double m_baseX;
    double m_baseY;
    public ReversePolarSorter(Point basePoint)
    {
        m_baseX = basePoint.X;
        m_baseY = basePoint.Y;
    }

    double GetAngle(Point p)
    {
        return Math.Round(Math.Atan2(p.Y - m_baseY, p.X - m_baseX), precision);
    }

    public override int Compare(Point a,  Point b)
    {
        return GetAngle(a).CompareTo(GetAngle(b));
    }
}
```

Also, note that the third argument of `Array.Sort` is the *length*, so if `m_pointsNumber` is a number of points and point at index `m_pointsNumber - 1` is the base point, then you should pass `m_pointsNumber - 1` as *length*:

```
Array.Sort(coords, 0, m_pointsNumber - 1, sorter);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
changing the length in Sort made the thing. I missed that it's length not index